# Number of permutation, where a set of numbers are positioned after another number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given n distinct numbers (from 1 to n). And a set of numbers $S = {\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{k-1}\}} \ where \ k<n$ and all are distinct and between $1$ to $n$. And another number be $a_k$. What is the number of permutation where the sets of number, S are always after $a_k$.

Example, for $n = 3$ and $S = \{2,3\}$ and $a_3=1$, we have $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,3,2\}$ i.e. $2$ ways.
Example, for $n = 4$ and $S = \{2,3\}$ and $a_3=1$, we have $\{4,1,2,3\}$, $\{1,4,2,3\},\{1,2,4,3\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{4,1,3,2\},\{1,4,3,2\},\{1,3,4,2\},\{1,3,2,4\}$ i.e. $8$ ways.

PS. I did some brute force with code, and it seems like the result is $\frac{n!}{k}$. But I can't prove it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Once again, this robot doesn't understand something which is clearly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct.

Select $k$ of the $n$ positions for the $k - 1$ numbers in $S$ and $a_k$, which can be done in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways.  To ensure that $a_k$ precedes each number in set $S$, the number $a_k$ must be in the first of these $k$ selected positions.  The $k - 1$ elements in $S$ can be arranged in the remaining $k - 1$ selected positions in $(k - 1)!$ ways.  The remaining $n - k$ numbers can be arranged in the remaining $n - k$ positions in $(n - k)!$ ways.  Hence, the number of permutations of $[n] = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ in which $a_k$ precedes each of the $k - 1$ elements in the subset $S = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{k - 1}\}$ of $[n]$ is
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}(k - 1)!(n - k)! & = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} \cdot (k - 1)!(n - k)!\\
& = \frac{n!}{k(k - 1)!(n - k)!} \cdot (k - 1)!(n - k)!\\
& = \frac{n!}{k}
\end{align*}